# HTML not format correctly in outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, email-templates

I have one of my email template, with line breaks, and it's not working properly in outlook email.

Same template working fine with gmail and all other providers.

I have used some of the below css for that!

overflow-wrap: break-word;
white-space: pre-line

But not works for outlook.

This are the snapshot you can check 
https://prnt.sc/o4w7v1 
https://prnt.sc/o4w6nu

I have attached that template.

In code you can see text : 
"Lorem Ipsum is...." which is formatted with space but it will not open correctly in outlook.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <head>
    <title>Got a minute to help?</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:100,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100i,300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
      }
      img {
      border: 0 !important;
      outline: none !important;
      }
      p {
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      }
      table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      mso-table-lspace: 0;
      mso-table-rspace: 0;
      }
      td, a, span {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
      }
      .ExternalClass * {
      line-height: 100%;
      }
      .cmm_defaultlink a {
      color: inherit !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      }
      span.MsoHyperlink {
      mso-style-priority: 99;
      color: inherit;
      }
      span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
      mso-style-priority: 99;
      color: inherit;
      }
      .date a {
      color: #777479;
      text-decoration: none;
      }
      .date2 a {
      color: #cccccc;
      text-decoration: none;
      }
      @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:599px) {
      .cmm_main_table {
      width: 100% !important;
      }
      .cmm_fix {
      width: 375px !important;
      margin:0 auto !important;
      }
      .cmm-240{width:240px !important;}
      .cmm_wrapper {
      width: 100% !important;
      }
      .cmm_aside {
      width: 20px !important;
      }
      .cmm_aside3 {
      width: 10px !important;
      }
      .cmm_hide {
      display: none !important;
      }
      .cmm_img {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
      } 
      .cmm_ft2 {
      font-size: 12px!important;
      line-height: 14px !important;
      }
      .cmm_ft1 {
      font-size: 30px!important;
      line-height: 37px !important;
      padding-bottom: 5px !important;
      } 
      .cmm_height{height:25px !important;}
      .cmm_bg {
      background-color: #9178a0 !important;
      height: 4px !important;
      margin-top: 10px !important;
      }
      .cmm_auto{height: auto !important;}
      .cmm-block{display:block !important;}
      }
      @media screen and (max-width:480px) {
      .cmm_main_table {
      width: 100% !important;
      }
      .cmm-240{width:240px !important;}
      .cmm_fix {
      max-width: 375px !important;
      margin:0 auto !important;
      }
      .cmm_height{height:25px !important;}
      .cmm_wrapper {
      width: 100% !important;
      }
      .cmm_aside {
      width: 20px !important;
      }
      .cmm_aside3 {
      width: 10px !important;
      }
      .cmm_hide {
      display: none !important;
      }
      .cmm_img {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
      } 
      .cmm_ft2 {
      font-size: 12px!important;
      line-height: 14px !important;
      }
      .cmm_ft1 {
      font-size: 30px!important;
      line-height: 37px !important;
      padding-bottom: 5px !important;
      } 
      .cmm_bg {
      background-color: #9178a0 !important;
      height: 4px !important;
      margin-top: 10px !important;
      }
      .cmm_auto{height: auto !important;}
      u + .cmm_body .cmm_fullbody {
      width: 100% !important;
      width: 100vw !important;
      }
      .cmm-block{display:block !important;}
      }
    </style>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <xml>
      <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:AllowPNG />
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
      </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if mso]>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body class="cmm_body" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <!--[if !gte mso 9]><!-->  
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="cmm_fullbody">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
          <table align="center" width="634" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="cmm_main_table" style="width:634px;table-layout: fixed;">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table width="634" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:634px;" class="cmm_wrapper">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right" valign="top" width="17" style="width:17px;" class="cmm_hide"></td>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" >
                      <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:600px;" class="cmm_wrapper">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="left" valign="top" class="cmm_bg" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;height:10px;" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" class="cmm_auto">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top:47px;padding-bottom:20px;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src='' width="125" height="" border="0" style="line-height:; max-width:; display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;" vspace="0" hspace="0" /></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td style="font-size: 36px; line-height: 36px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" height="36">
                                 &nbsp;
                                 </td>
                              </tr>                             
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;font-size:26px;line-height:125%;color:#000000;font-weight: 700; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;"><span class="cmm-block">Can you help a fellow Abhishek?</span></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" height="30" style="height:30px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;"  >&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>                              
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top:5px; font-family:'Roboto Slab', Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;font-size:16px;line-height:23px;color:#777479;font-weight: 300;padding-left:20px; padding-right:50px; overflow-wrap: break-word;white-space: pre-line;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu.
&nbsp;
Now is your chance!
&nbsp;
orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu 
&nbsp;
Scroll down to view a request that we have uniquely matched to you, based on the information you’ve shared with Duke about your interests. 
&nbsp;
orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu
&nbsp;
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td style="font-size: 36px; line-height: 36px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" height="36">
                                 &nbsp;
                                 </td>
                              </tr> 
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" height="5" style="height:5px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" height="18" style="height:18px;font-size:1px;line-height:18px;" class="cmm_height" ><hr></td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" height="36" style="height:36px;font-size:1px;line-height:36px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" >
                                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="left" valign="top" width="30" style="width:30px;" class="cmm_aside">&nbsp;</td>
                                      <td align="center" valign="top">
                                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                                              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                                                <tr>                                                  
                                                  <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Roboto Slab, Georgia,Times New Roman, Times, serif;font-size:17px;line-height:22px;color:#000000;font-weight: 700;'>Abhishek Panchal</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td align='left' valign='top' class='date' style='font-family: Roboto Slab, Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;font-size:13px;line-height:17px;color:#777479;'>abhishekp@mailinator.com</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                  </td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </table>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Roboto Slab', Georgia;
                                              font-size: 17px;
                                              line-height: 23px;
                                              color: #000000;
                                              font-weight: 300;white-space: pre-line;">Hi - 

My name iorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsus.

Iorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu

If you have any questions or information please contact me at abhi@mailinato.com and my phone number is (999)-123-4567.

Thank you!

Abhi Panchal
test@test.com
999-123-4567
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" height="1" style="height:1px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" height="1" style="height:1px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                  <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                    <table width="353" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="cmm_wrapper" style="width:353px;">
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                          <table width="166" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" class="cmm_wrapper" style="width:166px;">
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td align="center" valign="top" height="35" style="height:35px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                                <table width="166" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:166px;" class="cmm-240">
                                                                  <tr>
                                                                    <td align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#9178A0' height='40' style='height:40px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#1D1820;font-weight: 500;border-radius: 4px;'><a href='test' target='_blank' style='line-height:40px;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;display:block;border-radius:4px;'>Test</a></td>
                                                                  </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                              </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                          </table>
                                                          <table width="166" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" class="cmm_wrapper" style="width:166px;">
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td align="center" valign="top" height="35" style="height:35px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                                <table width="166" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:166px;" class="cmm-240">
                                                                  <tr>
                                                                    <td align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#CBA8E0' height='40' style='height:40px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#1D1820;font-weight: 500;border-radius: 4px;'><a href='test' target='_blank' style='line-height:40px;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;display:block;border-radius:4px;'>test</a></td>
                                                                  </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                              </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                          </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                  </td>                                                  
                                                </tr>
                                              </table>
                                            </td>                                            
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" height="1" style="height:1px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" height="1" style="height:1px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" height="1" style="height:1px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </table>
                                      </td>
                                      <td align="left" valign="top" width="30" style="width:30px;" class="cmm_aside">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" height="50" style="height:36px;font-size:1px;line-height:50px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top:5px; font-family:'Roboto Slab', Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;font-size:16px;line-height:23px;color:#777479;font-weight: 300;padding-left:20px; padding-right:50px;">
                          </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td align="left" valign="top" class="cmm_hide" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;height:40px;" ></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="17" style="width:17px;" class="cmm_hide"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="cmm_hide" style="white-space:nowrap;display:none;font-size:0px;line-height:0px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Can you add a screenshot of how it looks like in outlook?

Comment: @Ms.Tamil This are the snap shot you can check prnt.sc/o4w7v1 , prnt.sc/o4w6nu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All email clients doesn't support css3, you can use br tag instead of using nbsp; and overflow-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-lin;
If you want to increase the gaps simply use another br tag or increase the line height. 
Also if you can use multiple tr and give padding or height to the td

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <head>
    <title>Got a minute to help?</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:100,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100i,300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
      }
      img {
      border: 0 !important;
      outline: none !important;
      }
      p {
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      }
      table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      mso-table-lspace: 0;
      mso-table-rspace: 0;
      }
      td, a, span {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
      }
      .ExternalClass * {
      line-height: 100%;
      }
      .cmm_defaultlink a {
      color: inherit !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      }
      span.MsoHyperlink {
      mso-style-priority: 99;
      color: inherit;
      }
      span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
      mso-style-priority: 99;
      color: inherit;
      }
      .date a {
      color: #777479;
      text-decoration: none;
      }
      .date2 a {
      color: #cccccc;
      text-decoration: none;
      }
      @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:599px) {
      .cmm_main_table {
      width: 100% !important;
      }
      .cmm_fix {
      width: 375px !important;
      margin:0 auto !important;
      }
      .cmm-240{width:240px !important;}
      .cmm_wrapper {
      width: 100% !important;
      }
      .cmm_aside {
      width: 20px !important;
      }
      .cmm_aside3 {
      width: 10px !important;
      }
      .cmm_hide {
      display: none !important;
      }
      .cmm_img {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
      } 
      .cmm_ft2 {
      font-size: 12px!important;
      line-height: 14px !important;
      }
      .cmm_ft1 {
      font-size: 30px!important;
      line-height: 37px !important;
      padding-bottom: 5px !important;
      } 
      .cmm_height{height:25px !important;}
      .cmm_bg {
      background-color: #9178a0 !important;
      height: 4px !important;
      margin-top: 10px !important;
      }
      .cmm_auto{height: auto !important;}
      .cmm-block{display:block !important;}
      }
      @media screen and (max-width:480px) {
      .cmm_main_table {
      width: 100% !important;
      }
      .cmm-240{width:240px !important;}
      .cmm_fix {
      max-width: 375px !important;
      margin:0 auto !important;
      }
      .cmm_height{height:25px !important;}
      .cmm_wrapper {
      width: 100% !important;
      }
      .cmm_aside {
      width: 20px !important;
      }
      .cmm_aside3 {
      width: 10px !important;
      }
      .cmm_hide {
      display: none !important;
      }
      .cmm_img {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
      } 
      .cmm_ft2 {
      font-size: 12px!important;
      line-height: 14px !important;
      }
      .cmm_ft1 {
      font-size: 30px!important;
      line-height: 37px !important;
      padding-bottom: 5px !important;
      } 
      .cmm_bg {
      background-color: #9178a0 !important;
      height: 4px !important;
      margin-top: 10px !important;
      }
      .cmm_auto{height: auto !important;}
      u + .cmm_body .cmm_fullbody {
      width: 100% !important;
      width: 100vw !important;
      }
      .cmm-block{display:block !important;}
      }
    </style>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <xml>
      <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:AllowPNG />
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
      </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if mso]>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body class="cmm_body" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <!--[if !gte mso 9]><!-->  
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="cmm_fullbody">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
          <table align="center" width="634" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="cmm_main_table" style="width:634px;table-layout: fixed;">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table width="634" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:634px;" class="cmm_wrapper">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right" valign="top" width="17" style="width:17px;" class="cmm_hide"></td>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" >
                      <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:600px;" class="cmm_wrapper">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="left" valign="top" class="cmm_bg" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;height:10px;" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" class="cmm_auto">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top:47px;padding-bottom:20px;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src='' width="125" height="" border="0" style="line-height:; max-width:; display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;" vspace="0" hspace="0" /></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td style="font-size: 36px; line-height: 36px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" height="36">
                                 &nbsp;
                                 </td>
                              </tr>                             
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;font-size:26px;line-height:125%;color:#000000;font-weight: 700; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;"><span class="cmm-block">Can you help a fellow Abhishek?</span></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" height="30" style="height:30px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;"  >&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>                              
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top:5px; font-family:'Roboto Slab', Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;font-size:16px;line-height:23px;color:#777479;font-weight: 300;padding-left:20px; padding-right:50px;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu.
<br><br>
Now is your chance!
<br><br>
orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu 
<br><br>
Scroll down to view a request that we have uniquely matched to you, based on the information you’ve shared with Duke about your interests. 
<br><br>
orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu
<br><br>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td style="font-size: 36px; line-height: 36px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" height="36">
                                 &nbsp;
                                 </td>
                              </tr> 
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" height="5" style="height:5px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" height="18" style="height:18px;font-size:1px;line-height:18px;" class="cmm_height" ><hr></td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" height="36" style="height:36px;font-size:1px;line-height:36px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" >
                                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="left" valign="top" width="30" style="width:30px;" class="cmm_aside">&nbsp;</td>
                                      <td align="center" valign="top">
                                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                                              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                                                <tr>                                                  
                                                  <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Roboto Slab, Georgia,Times New Roman, Times, serif;font-size:17px;line-height:22px;color:#000000;font-weight: 700;'>Abhishek Panchal</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td align='left' valign='top' class='date' style='font-family: Roboto Slab, Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;font-size:13px;line-height:17px;color:#777479;'>abhishekp@mailinator.com</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                  </td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </table>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Roboto Slab', Georgia;
                                              font-size: 17px;
                                              line-height: 23px;
                                              color: #000000;
                                              font-weight: 300;">Hi - 

My name iorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsus.
<br><br>
Iorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu
<br><br>
If you have any questions or information please contact me at abhi@mailinato.com and my phone number is (999)-123-4567.
<br><br>
Thank you!
<br><br>
Abhi Panchal<br>
test@test.com<br>
999-123-4567<br>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" height="1" style="height:1px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" height="1" style="height:1px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                  <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                    <table width="353" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="cmm_wrapper" style="width:353px;">
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                          <table width="166" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" class="cmm_wrapper" style="width:166px;">
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td align="center" valign="top" height="35" style="height:35px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                                <table width="166" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:166px;" class="cmm-240">
                                                                  <tr>
                                                                    <td align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#9178A0' height='40' style='height:40px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#1D1820;font-weight: 500;border-radius: 4px;'><a href='test' target='_blank' style='line-height:40px;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;display:block;border-radius:4px;'>Test</a></td>
                                                                  </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                              </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                          </table>
                                                          <table width="166" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" class="cmm_wrapper" style="width:166px;">
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td align="center" valign="top" height="35" style="height:35px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                                <table width="166" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:166px;" class="cmm-240">
                                                                  <tr>
                                                                    <td align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#CBA8E0' height='40' style='height:40px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#1D1820;font-weight: 500;border-radius: 4px;'><a href='test' target='_blank' style='line-height:40px;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;display:block;border-radius:4px;'>test</a></td>
                                                                  </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                              </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                          </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                  </td>                                                  
                                                </tr>
                                              </table>
                                            </td>                                            
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" height="1" style="height:1px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" height="1" style="height:1px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" height="1" style="height:1px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </table>
                                      </td>
                                      <td align="left" valign="top" width="30" style="width:30px;" class="cmm_aside">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" height="50" style="height:36px;font-size:1px;line-height:50px;" class="cmm_height" >&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top:5px; font-family:'Roboto Slab', Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;font-size:16px;line-height:23px;color:#777479;font-weight: 300;padding-left:20px; padding-right:50px;">
                          </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td align="left" valign="top" class="cmm_hide" style="font-size:0px;line-height:0px;height:40px;" ></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="17" style="width:17px;" class="cmm_hide"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="cmm_hide" style="white-space:nowrap;display:none;font-size:0px;line-height:0px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </div>
  </body>
</html>
```